# ¿Cómo cambiar formato de la fecha en PHP?

Tags: php, php7

Lo que quiero es cambiar una fecha con el formato d/m/y al formato Y-m-d y no al revés.

Entiendo que al revés es más sencillo, por ejemplo:

```
$date=date_create("2013-03-15");
echo date_format($date,"d/m/y");
```

Pero si hago eso partiendo de mi formato d/m/y se va a confundir y me tomará el día como mes. Lo más cerca que he podido llegar fue con:

```
$test = new DateTime('06/31/2011');
echo date_format($test, 'Y-m-d');
```

Así que, la pregunta del millón es ¿cómo le digo a PHP que la fecha de entrada tiene este formato d/m/y y que quiero una salida con el formato Y-m-d. Imagino que esto último se haría con:

`date_format($test, 'Y-m-d');`

Comment: exacto ¿cómo le digo a PHP que el primero es el día? obviamente en ese ejemplo es sencillo ¿pero qué ocurriría si recibo un 06/06/99? necesitaría la siguiente salida: 1999-06-06

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te recomiendo que uses la clase `DateTime` y sus métodos basados en el estilo orientado a objetos por su claridad.

Para crear una fecha basada en un determinado formato puedes usar [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.createfromformat.php) y para mostrarla como quieras, usar `format`.

Veamos:

```
#Creamos la fecha según el formato de entrada
$mDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', '06/30/2011');
echo $mDate->format('Y-m-d');   # 2011-06-30
```

Ten en cuenta que el formato es algo contextual, y que estás trabajando con objetos. Significa que una vez creado `$mDate` puedes darle el formato que quieras en la salida, según necesites:

```
echo $mDate->format('Y');   # 2011 (año)
echo $mDate->format('W');   # 26 (semana del año)
echo $mDate->format('t');   # 30 (total de días del mes dado)
// etc
```

Como dije antes, el formato es algo contextual. Significa que si en algún contexto tienes fechas en este formato (u otro cualquiera): `2011 06 30`, puedes crear un objeto `DateTime` indicando lo que tienes en ese contexto:

```
$mDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y m d', '2011 06 30');
echo $mDate->format('Y-m-d');   # 2011-06-30
echo $mDate->format('Y/m/d');   # 2011/06/30
echo $mDate->format('d/m/Y');   # 30/06/2011
// etc
```

La **condición** que debes garantizar siempre es que la fecha sea válida y el formato que indiques también.

En los `echo` de prueba anteriores, `$mDate` es **siempre el mismo objeto**, sobre el cual podemos usar `format()` o cualquier otro de los métodos de `DateTime` para trabajar con **esa instancia** del objeto. Y lo puedes usar con otros objetos para obtener intervalos por ejemplo, simplificando operaciones que de otro modo serían bastante complejas. Esta es una de las grandes ventajas de la Programación Orientada a Objetos (POO).

Comment: Muchas gracias A.Cedano